# Why doesn't object with finalizer get collected even if it is unrooted?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I've encountered an issue with finalizable objects that doesn't get collected by `GC` if `Dispose()` wasn't called explicitly.
I know that I should call `Dispose()` explicitly if an object implements `IDisposable`, but I always thought that it is safe to rely upon framework and when an object becomes unreferenced it can be collected.

But after some experiments with windbg/sos/sosex I've found that if **GC.SuppressFinalize()** wasn't called for finalizable object it doesn't get collected, even if it becomes unrooted. So, if you extensively use finalizable objects(DbConnection, FileStream, etc) and not disposing them explicitly you can encounter too high memory consumption or even `OutOfMemoryException`.

Here is a sample application:

```
public class MemoryTest
{
    private HundredMegabyte hundred;

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ready to attach");
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("iteration #{0}", i + 1);
            hundred = new HundredMegabyte();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} object was initialized", hundred);
            Console.ReadKey();
            //hundred.Dispose();
            hundred = null;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var test = new MemoryTest();
        test.Run();
    }
}

public class HundredMegabyte : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Megabyte[] megabytes = new Megabyte[100];

    public HundredMegabyte()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < megabytes.Length; i++)
        {
            megabytes[i] = new Megabyte();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~HundredMegabyte()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}MB", megabytes.Length);
    }
}

public class Megabyte
{
    private readonly Kilobyte[] kilobytes = new Kilobyte[1024];

    public Megabyte()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < kilobytes.Length; i++)
        {
            kilobytes[i] = new Kilobyte();
        }
    }
}

public class Kilobyte
{
    private byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
}
```

Even after 10 iterations you can find that memory consumption is too high(from 700MB to 1GB) and gets even higher with more iterations. After attaching to process with WinDBG you can find that all large objects are unrooted, but not collected.

Situation changes if you call `SuppressFinalize()` explicitly: memory consumption is stable around 300-400MB even under high pressure and WinDBG shows that there are no unrooted objects, memory is free.

So the question is: Is it a bug in framework? Is there any logical explanation?

More details:

After each iteration, windbg shows that:

- finalization queue is empty
- freachable queue is empty
- generation 2 contains objects(Hundred) from previous iterations
- objects from previous iterations are unrooted

Comment: I tried running it and I got it up to 700mb, at which point it cut down to 100mb or so on its own. (I just kept pressing return and watched the memory usage in Task Manager). Running Windows 8.

Comment: Very interesting... i've have tested it on win7 x64. First 10 iterations with one second pause, after that just hold any key... outofmemory

Comment: Tried again, but got to 100 iterations without an exception. Also 64-bit, but pretty interesting. Maybe someone else can also test and post results.

Comment: I have the same issue: [objects stuck in gen 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111289/cli-native-objects-getting-stuck-in-gen2-and-not-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An object with a finalizer doesn't behave the same way as an object lacking one.

When a GC occurs, and SuppressFinalize has not been called, the GC won't be able to collect the instance, because it must execute the Finalizer. Therefore, the finalizer is executed, AND the object instance is promoted to generation 1 (object which survived a first GC), even if it's already without any living reference.

Generation 1 (and Gen2) objects are considered long lived, and will be considered for garbage collection only if a Gen1 GC isn't sufficient to free enough memory. I think that during your test, Gen1 GC is always sufficient.

This behavior has an impact on GC performance, as it negates the optimisation brought by having several générations (you have short duration objects in the gen1 ).

Essentially, having a Finalizer and failing to prevent the GC from calling it will always promote already dead objects to the long lived heap, which isn't a good thing.

You should therefore Dispose properly your IDisposable objects AND avoid Finalizers if not necessary (and if necessary, implement IDisposable and call GC.SuppressFinalize. )

**Edit:**
I didn't read the code example well enough: Your data looks like it is meant to reside in the Large Object Heap (LOH), but in fact isn't: You have a lot of small arrays of references containing at the end of the tree small arrays of bytes.

Putting short duration object in the LOH is even worse, as they won't be compacted... And therefore you could run OutOfMemory with lot of free memory, if the CLR isn't able to find an empty memory segment long enough to contains a large chunk of data.

Comment: +1 as i agree with every statement, but i want to wait if anybody have encountered the same issues. This sample application is just a simplified version of our production environment where it seems that some of used frameworks(EF, spring.net, log4net) doesn't call Dispose() for streams and sqlcommands...

Comment: i've checked your suggestion about 2nd generation and found that even if finalizer is commented out, most of the objects are allocated(or moved) on 2nd generation. So 2nd gen is definitely not the cause of this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you triggered an GC? The CLR won't trigger one unless you run out of memory. Try to call GC.Collect() to ensure that it's run.

Comment: After Your edit: My data is NOT reside on LOH. all arrays are smaller that 85KB...

Comment: GC.Collect() DOES help in this sample application, memory consumption become stable at 200-250MB! Much better than explicit Dispose(). But I'm not sure if I should use GC.Collect() in production environment...

Comment: Ok, then you have small arrays of references (megabytes array) containing small arrays of references (kilobytes array) containing a small array of bytes (bytes array). It's a trap. At midnight, I fall right into it -_-'

Comment: You shouldn't rely on GC.Collect. The fact is that .NET won't garbage collect the heap unless it needs to do it. Don't worry about it, (and don't forget to call dispose)

Comment: I can't stop worrying about it because i have several processes(WCF, ASP.NET) each about 1GB in production and all of them are in idle state :) From my experience these processes should not exceed 200-300MB. After debugging with windbg i've found that 90% of live objects are unrooted and GC does nothing with them

Comment: If they're all in an idle state, then you have no pressure on the system and hence not much need for a GC. The GC reacts to pressure (memory segments filling up, low memory notifications from the OS, etc), and collects at these times. It doesn't decide your process has been quiet for a while and so the GC should run. Gen 2 colletions are expensive, hence the GC avoids them until necessary. That's why your objects are unrooted and uncollected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea behind this is, when you implement IDisposable, it's because you are handling unmanaged resources, and require to dispose your resource manually.

If the GC was to call Dispose or try to get rid of it, it would flush the unmanaged stuff too, which can very well be used somewhere else, the GC has no way to know that.

If the GC was to removed unrooted object, you would lose reference toward unmanaged resource which would lead to memory leaks.

So... You're managed, or your not. There is simply no good way for the GC to handle not-disposed IDisposables.